# jpg giving 403 error

Tags: html, image, http-status-code-403

I have a lot of jpg files in a directory.  One of these will not show on 3 different web pages (the rest all do). Trying to open it with a direct url throws a 403 error.

Used chrome and IE on 2 machines  - no difference
Used Chrome Dev Tools  and did empty cache and hard reload

The html is the same for all the images except for the file name.

I have code to show that the file exists - the web page sees it
Web page also shows the alt for the image

Spelling and extension are correct

Folder and permissions are the same for all files

I have changed the name

I have saved it in photoshop as a psd then saved again as a jpg (thought it might 'clean' the file)

I have converted it to a webp and that also gives a 403

I can open the file using explorer on my local machine, using photoshop on my local machine, and explorer on my web server - so the file does't appear corrupt -

it just won't open on a web page
I am using google/IIS compression but this hasn't had any affect on several hundred other images

running on IIS 7.5

sample page below

https://kevin-sandbox.com/ovmp-dev/HtmlPage2.html

would anyone have any ideas on what might be wrong?
Thanks

Update
I added a screenshot to the HTML file showing
image - directory listing - permissions - log entry

Comment: _“would anyone have any ideas on what might be wrong?”_ – the server error log maybe …?

Comment: see if I can check them out ... going into foreign territory

Comment: Are you sure that file exists with that name? Opening the image directly in the browser doesn't work.

Comment: log - this is from a different page with the same file                                shows 2017-03-09 16:17:56 W3SVC2 173.0.140.65 GET /ovmp-dev/images/gallery/franklin-car-wash/franklin-customer-service.jpg - 443 - 81.130.135.221 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36 403 0 0 213 488 271

Comment: the file does exist - I have several pages that look for - one is a upload/manage page. I use File.Exists on this page and it returns true.  I can also open the file if I go directly to it on the server - opens no problem

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to configure IIS's [Dynamic IP Restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/using-dynamic-ip-restrictions). Too many requests in a short amount of time can cause IIS to temporarily block IP's. This was the issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

There is file permission issue

```
sudo chmod ugo+rwx *.jpg
```

For more help, refer this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

Comment: It would appear to be but I believe I have ruled that out.  All the other images in that folder work, so its not a folder permission issue.  At the file level it appears that this and other images all have the same permissions. I originally uploaded all the images at the same time from a common folder (FTP) so I don't know how the one file would somehow have an issue and not the others - plus I have renamed it several times, etc

Comment: Please give 755 folder permission and 644 permission for all files. also check group user is same as https://kevin-sandbox.com/ovmp-dev/images/gallery/franklin-car-wash/wash-bay-lava-wax.jpg

Comment: @calypso: IIS can only run on Windows OS. Nothing here about Ubuntu

Comment: not exactly sure what 755 and 644 are - I just changed the file to have all permissions for IIS_IUSRS  -- this is the user name for the web site and is the same for all files - the ones that work have lower permissions that what I just changed this to